# How can I do a loop in data table columns?

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I know how to functions and loops, and I want to combine them with a data table object with the objetive of make a exploratory data analysis.

I made this function:

```
aed <- function(x) {
  mean       <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  desvtip    <- sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  qss        <- quantile(x, probs=c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99, 1), na.rm=TRUE)
  names(qss) <- NULL
  min        <- qss[1]
  p1         <- qss[2]
  p5         <- qss[3]
  p25        <- qss[4]
  median     <- qss[5]
  p75        <- qss[6]
  p95        <- qss[7]
  p99        <- qss[8]
  max        <- qss[9]
  ric        <- p75-p25

return( c(mean=mean, st=desvtip, min=min, p1=p1, p5=p5, p25=p25, p50=median,
p75=p75, p95=p95,p99=p99, max=max,rangic=ric))
}
```

And I have a data table (called Master) like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 532.215 | *float_value* | *float_value* | *float_value* |
| 123.258 | *float_value* | *float_value* | *float_value* |
| 0.025 | *float_value* | *float_value* | *float_value* |

Every column is float type.

So, I want to use a loop to process every column with my function and make a table results like this:

| Column_Name | Mean | st | Min | Max | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V1 | *mean of V1* | *st of V1* | ... | ... | ... |
| V2 | *mean of V2* | *st of V2* | ... | ... | ... |
| V3 | *mean of V3* | *st of V3* | ... | ... | ... |
| V4 | *mean of V4* | *st of V4* | ... | ... | ... |

I've tried to make a loop like this.

```
results <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(Master)) {       # for-loop over columns
  
  col_name <- colnames(Master)[i] #select column name
  analysis <- aed(Master[,paste0(colnames(Master)[i])]) #use my function
  r_row <- cbind(col_name, analysis) #combine column name and resuts of aed in a row
 
 results <- rbind(results, r_row) # combine every row in a table
}
```

The part that I don't understand is why `Master[,paste0(colnames(Master)[i])]` when i = 1 is not the same that `Master[,"V1"]`.

The console return:

```
> Master[,paste0(colnames(Master)[i])] # when i =1
[1] "V1"

> Master[,"V1"]
   V1
1:           0
2:           2
3:           2
4:           0
5:           0
6:           0
```

Can someone help me please? It's not necessary to use my loop if you have a better idea, but if someone can explain me why `Master[,paste0(colnames(Master)[i])]` doesn't work I'll be very greatful.

Comment: FYI, the tag-recommendation system is imperfect. Please check the tags suggested before posting your question. In this case, you had [tag:datatable] which is ambiguous but in its description it explicitly says *"for the data.table R package please use [tag:data.table]"*; also the [tag:rstudio] tag is only for questions about the IDE, and its description says *"DO NOT use this tag for general R programming problems"*.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a `for` loop. In fact, iteratively `rbind`ing data to a table works bus is very inefficient and scales horribly, see the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) chapter 2, *Growing objects*.

Here's an adaptation of your `aed` function:

```r
aed <- function(nm, x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  percentiles <- c(0, 1, 5, 25, 50, 75, 95, 99, 100)
  qss <- setNames(quantile(x, percentiles/100, na.rm = na.rm), paste0("p", percentiles))
  names(qss)[c(1,5,9)] <- c("min", "median", "max")
  vals <- c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = na.rm), st = sd(x, na.rm = na.rm), qss, rangeic = qss["p75"] - qss["p25"])
  m <- matrix(vals, nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, names(vals)))
  cbind(data.table(Column_Name = nm), m)
}
```

Some sample data, I have no idea if it matches what you're using.

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(V1 = runif(1000), V2 = runif(1000))
dat
#                V1         V2
#             <num>      <num>
#    1: 0.914806043 0.84829322
#    2: 0.937075413 0.06274633
#    3: 0.286139535 0.81984509
#    4: 0.830447626 0.53936029
#    5: 0.641745519 0.49902010
#    6: 0.519095949 0.02222732
#    7: 0.736588315 0.55409313
#    8: 0.134666597 0.71989760
#    9: 0.656992290 0.23571523
#   10: 0.705064784 0.81187968
#   ---                       
#  991: 0.750519822 0.72004398
#  992: 0.097692942 0.98333927
#  993: 0.815567016 0.16192736
#  994: 0.858393029 0.76617988
#  995: 0.117157300 0.95396922
#  996: 0.137397162 0.26590719
#  997: 0.548256997 0.08583757
#  998: 0.059029650 0.22892575
#  999: 0.495523291 0.33242952
# 1000: 0.007417523 0.95179901
```

Its use:

```r
dat[, rbindlist(Map(aed, names(.SD), .SD))]
#    Column_Name      mean        st          min          p1         p5       p25    median       p75       p95       p99       max   rangeic
#         <char>     <num>     <num>        <num>       <num>      <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>
# 1:          V1 0.4882555 0.2914302 0.0002388966 0.006891313 0.04862636 0.2294261 0.4803411 0.7439418 0.9445328 0.9826610 0.9984908 0.5145157
# 2:          V2 0.4970157 0.2961325 0.0003734785 0.010906180 0.04513135 0.2385863 0.5024530 0.7563358 0.9514749 0.9927716 0.9997632 0.5177495
```

Comment: First, thanks for you solution and thanks for your tip about Rbind. Only for curiosity, do you know why `dat[,paste0(colnames(dat)[i])]` doesn't work like `dat[,"V1"]`?

Comment: Yes, because `data.table` does its NSE a little differently. With a `data.table` object, you can do `dat[,paste0(colnames(dat)[i]),with=FALSE]` to force what you want, and it returns a 1-column `data.table`; or you can coerce (at least temporarily) to a `data.frame` with `as.data.frame(dat)[,paste0(colnames(dat)[i])]`, and it returns a vector. BTW, `paste0` is doing nothing in all of that, just use `dat[,colnames(dat)[i]]` in whichever variant you prefer.

Comment: Another option: you have a column number, just use it: `dat[,i]` returns a 1-column `data.table`; `as.data.frame(dat)[,i]` returns a vector; `dat[[i]]` always returns a vector, regardless of `data.table` or `data.frame`.

Comment: You could avoid dealing with matrix creation and cbinding if you replace the last two lines of the function with `c(Column_Name = nm, as.list(vals))`